# Singly Linked Circular List Add method

Tags: java, circular-list

I am creating a singly linked circular list and I don't seem to understand why it is not working. Here is my code. Would someone help me and point out what am I doing wrong? I am able to add the first node but I don't understand how to add the second node. Could someone show me how to change it. I think my list is traversing endlessly that's why.

```
public class CircularList <E> {
       private Node<E> head;

       private class Node <E>
       {
          E data;
          Node <E> next;

          public Node(E data, Node<E> next)
          {
             this.data = data;
             this.next = next;
          }
          public Node(E data)
          {
             this.data = data;
             this.next = null;          
          }
       }//node
       public CircularList()
       {
          head = null;

       }

       public void add(E data)
       {
           Node <E> temp = new Node <E> (data);
           if(head==null)
           {
               head=temp;
               temp.next=temp;
               System.out.println(head.next.data);
            }
           else
           {
               Node<E> temp2 = head.next;
               while(temp2!=head)
               {
                   if(temp2.next==head)
                   {
                       temp2.next=temp;
                       temp.next=head;
                   }
                   temp2=temp2.next;
               }

           }
       }
```

Comment: The problems is that after you add the first node you will find that head == head.next, which is basically the check you are doing in the in the while. The if not be part of the loop, just use the while to move in the last node, and do the add outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your else part with this;

```
           Node<E> temp2 = head;
           while(temp2.next != head)
           {
               temp2=temp2.next;
           }
           temp2.next=temp;
           temp.next=head;
```

Comment: Thank you. that worked. And also I have to create a remove method method which removes an element at a specified index. I don't know how to deal with that.

Comment: Do it same as add method, just count number of elements and then remove element at that index. Be careful with edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to make your singly linked list circular, it would be a good idea to have a tail, then your code can be something along the lines of (pseudo code)

```
function addElement(data){

    Node n = new Node(data)

    if(list.isEmpty() ){
         head = n
         tail = n
         n.setNext(n)
    } else {
        n.setNext(head)
        tail.setNext(n)
        head = n
    }
}
```